# NGINX Proxy pass all urls except the homepage

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am trying to setup a proxy so that all pages except the homepage will be gotten from a remote server.. currently i have this config which uses the proxy servers 404 page.. i need to run 2 sites on different servers, one site will serve only the homepage, while the other will server all other pages.. both are running wordpress

```
    server {

    listen 8080;
    server_name        example.com;

    location = / { 
        index               index.html index.php;
        root                /var/www/example.com;
    }

    location / { 
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass http://213.21.232.23;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Prefix based matches (ie /) are chosen above exact matches (ie =) - [source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms). I did a bit of reading but can't find an easy answer for you. Hopefully someone will come up with something for you.

Comment: You want to have two domains on one `nginx`?